# My Search engine code in php giving me no result

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I am making search engine in php,but i am receiving no or 0 result. When I search for keywords that is in my database it showed me no result. can anybody please help me that where i am doing wrong.. Below is my code.

```
<?php
    $k = $_GET['k'];
    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM search WHERE ");
    foreach($terms as $each){
      $i++;

      if($i == 1)
         $query.= (" 'keywords' LIKE '%$each%' ");

      else
         $query.= (" OR 'keywords' LIKE '%$each%' ");
    }

    //Connect to db
    require("./db.php");

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if( $numrows>0 ){
     while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )

        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $link = $row['link'];

        echo "<h2><a href = '$link'>$title</a></h2> $description </br> </br>";

    }
    else
        echo "No results were found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";

    //Disconnect to db
    mysql_close();

    ?>
```

Comment: declare $i before incrementing.

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from PHP. You're also exposed to some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here because you're not [properly escaping your values](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: You could research a bit more and give us some examples... in any case, **don't use mysql_query**.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by tadman, you need to escape your input (hints, use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) functions and use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or perhaps pdo).

With that said, I think you need to remove the quotes from your keywords column name like so:

```
if($i == 1)
    $query.= (" keywords LIKE '%$each%' ");
else
    $query.= (" OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ");
```

Comment: I used mysqli functions but still its not working. @Jacob Oettinger.

Comment: Mysqli functions is not to get it working, that was just because mysql_* is deprecated. Did you try changing your query as I have shown above?

Comment: Yes I changed the query as you shown above but still it did not work. @Jacob Oettinger

Comment: Ok, it is hard to say anything else without more information. Have you  have you tried echo'ing the query you are building at and tried running manually? Do you get any error messages? Have you checked for mysql errors using mysqli_error?

Comment: Yes I tried everything. I am not getting any error messages. Everything works fine but i am not getting the correct result. I think something wrong in the while loop but not figuring it out. @Jacob Oettinger

Comment: The loop looks good to me. The only way to get any further is for you to make a minimal example that I can try. So maybe update the code in your question to what you have now, and move the connect code into the script, and add some sql statements that create the table and inserts a bit of test data.